# Umlauts in filenames using the grffile package

Tags: graphics, pdftex, miktex, input-encodings

**"Never ever use non-ASCII characters and spaces in your filenames. Never!"**

That's what I'm telling my students for years. But if for any reasons there is an urgent need to include an image file with umlauts in its filename, the `grffile` package could be used.

Unfortunately, I was not able to get the following example compiled:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[extendedchars]{grffile}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{Bäckerstraße}

\end{document}
```

I'm using MiKTeX (recently updated) upon Windows 7. My MWE is saved in `Cp1252` Windows encoding. The same is valid for the existing file `Bäckerstraße.png` on my file system.

I compiled with `pdflatex`. The compilation produces no PDF output with no error message in the log file. The compilations stops with an error message in the command shell:

`pdflatex: Windows API error 1113: F��r das Unicode-Zeichen ist kein zugeordnetes Zeichen in der Mehrbytecodepage vorhanden.`

I googled for this problem and found some forum discussion from 2011 and 2012 indicating that this could be a general `pdflatex` problem using MiKTeX.

I'm asking, if there is just a dumb error of mine inside the MWE code or if there is just no chance to run this with MiKTeX.

If there is an error in the MWE, please, let me know how to correct it. But if this cannot run at all, please, stop me wasting time trying.

Comment: Well, under Linux it works without problems...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think this could be MiKTeX-specific. http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?71899-graphicx-Umlaut-im-dateinamen-Miktex-Versionsproblem contains some discussion in this direction (dating from 2011).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test your issue more specifically... I neither use MikTeX nor Windows (;-))

Comment: No, miktex doesn't like non-ascii-chars (imho the problem did disappear sometime ago and then reappeared again). I wouldn't waste time on it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the information. I thought I could try some nice LaTeX image examples before sunday lunch, but this obviously was a bad idea. If you provide your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: What happens if you recode to UTF-8?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Recoding the MWE in UTF-8 seems to work!

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I found the solution for `latin1`. I have to use `\usepackage[encoding,filenameencoding=utf-8]{grffile}`. I thought that UTF-8 filename encoding would be wrong for Windows, but this option setting works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the file name encoding seems to be UTF-8, the file name needs to be reencoded from Latin-1 to UTF-8. This is also supported by package `grffile`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[encoding,filenameencoding=utf8]{grffile}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{Bäckerstraße}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively the TeX source could be encoded in UTF-8 entirely.

BTW, the full range of code page for CP 1252 is provided by options `ansinew` or `x-cp1252` for package `inputenc` (the latter option comes from package `inputenx` and can be used as `cp1252` there).