# Filenames and ps2pdf

Tags: miktex, accents, winedt, filesystem-access, ps2pdf

System: Windows 10, MikTeX 2.9, WinEdt 10.2

Workflow: tex -> ps -> pdf

Problem: I created a file named "TeoriaTehtäviä.tex" containing two characters outside the 7 bit ASCII range. Here's what happened:

- LaTeX (run within WinEdt) runs without any problems.
- The built-in program "dvips" (IIRC comes with MikTeX) has no problems whatsoever creating a corresponding file "TeoriaTehtäviä.ps". I can view that just fine with GSView.
- But, the attempt to convert this to pdf by clicking the "ps2pdf" button (IIRC another program that came with MikTeX) gives the error message:
  *Error: /undefinedfilename in (TeoriaTehtvi.ps)*. This is in a sense not a surprise because no file with such name exists.

---

The problem is obviously with the characters that fall outside the range of 7-bit ASCII. We have related posts such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213559/9446). And I can solve my problem just fine by using another file name. But, I still have the questions:

- Is there a fix to this problem?
- Why is this not a problem for "dvips", but "ps2pdf" acts up? In other words, why different component programs of MikTeX behave differently?

I'm afraid I also somewhat miffed that even in 2019 it is still possible to run into problems like this :-(.

**Update:**

- A per suggestion from AlexG, I tested it within Windows PowerShell. I
  got the exact same error message.
- I also tried calling `mgs.exe TeoriaTehtäviä.ps TeoriaTehtäviä.pdf` (`mgs` is a version of Ghostscript that came with MikTeX) within Windows PowerShell. In the command prompt the error message changed slightly to read *Error: /undefinedfilename in (TeoriaTeht\303\244vi\303\244.pdf)*. In other words, instead of dropping the characters they were substituted by their extended codes.

Comment: This is operating-system related. In my case, a unicode-enabled Linux system, there is no problem converting a PS file with umlauts (äöüß) in the file name to PDF using `ps2pdf` in a terminal.

Comment: Thanks for testing this @AlexG. Much appreciated. That still does not explain why `dvips` and `ps2pdf` behave differently. Scratches head :-)

Comment: You invoke all programs from within your editor. Did you try running them on the command line (`cmd.exe`or PowerShell)? Maybe it is only an editor (WinEdit) problem.

Comment: I would suggest a bug report in the miktex issue tracker. In texlive it works, and mgs itself seems to work too, so it is perhaps a problem in the ps2pdf and follow up scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlexG. I tested it within Windows PowerShell(x86). The error message was the same. Wonder whether some command line options would help? This makes it sound like it is not a problem caused by WinEdt.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @UlrikeFischer. I will do that.

Comment: Another option could be using stock Ghostscript instead of the version shipping with MikTeX. Cf. old question of yours : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214616

Comment: @AlexG I checked out that as well. The version of `mgs.exe` in my MikTeX-directory is apparently version 9.25 (dated Sept 25, 2018). I had installed a newer version of `gswin64` (version 9.27, dated April 4, 2019). Renaming that to `mgs.exe` like back in the day (thanks for remembering!) did not help me. At least I should be able to use `animate` without problems :-)